# How to test Universal in the App Clip locally?

Tags: swift, react-native

How to test & debug the universal link in the App Clip iOS app, Anyone please provide the steps on how we can test the universal link on the iPhone device?

App Clip is unable to open when clicking on the universal link because we need to find the link parameters.